# Is 'new Class[] {iface}' and 'new Class<?>[] {iface}' the same in Java

Tags: java

Are the two statements equal in Java?

```
//code 1
Object o1[] = new Class[] {iface};
//code 2
Object o2[] = new Class<?>[] {iface};
```

Comment: The important point here is that they get put in an `Object[]`. If it weren't for that the answer would be a little different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is effectively the same in this case.

Here

```
Object o1[] = new Class[] {iface};
```

you're using a raw type with an unparameterized `Class` type.

Here

```
Object o2[] = new Class<?>[] {iface};
```

you're using a parameterized `Class` type but with a wildcard.

Neither affect what can go into the array.

Since your reference is of type `Object[]`, you can't rely on any further type safety anyway, so they are equivalent.

[Vulcan, in the comments,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189356/is-new-class-iface-and-new-class-iface-the-same-in-java#comment33682449_22189401) brings up a good point that the raw type will create warnings for you during compilation. You might want to avoid that.

Comment: +1. Since Java 5, the version with a wildcard is favorable; the unparameterized version will create a compilation warning.

Comment: Note that while they are the same for arrays, they are not the same for lists. You cannot add anything to a `List<?>` for example (whereas you can add everything to a non-parameterized `List`). For backwards-compatibility reasons, arrays are not as strict here ( you can do a `o2[0] = String.class` even on the `Class<?>[]`).